# Confusion in definition of Bound states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, scattering

If the energy is less than the potential at $-\infty$ and $\infty$, then the eigenstate of Hamiltonian is called as a bound state.
But consider the case where a particle is coming from the left with some wavefunction $\Psi(x,0)$ and meets a potential barrier with the height $V_0$. I can calculate the evolution of the wavefunction with time i.e., $\Psi(x,t)$
After interacting with barrier, there will be some probability to reflect and some to transmit depending on the energy difference of Particle and barrier.
In this case particle has less energy than potential at $-\infty$ and $\infty$ but the particle is either reflected or transmitted accross the barrier. Then the particle is not "Bounded" per se , right?  because the particle is not "Bounded" by anything
Where am I wrong?

Comment: It only makes sense to say a particle "meets a potential barrier" if it used to have $E > V$. So I don't know why you said it has less energy than potential at $-\infty$ and $\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. You need a "closed" system for a bound state to exit, for example, infinite/finite potential well. For a system like potential barrier, an incoming particle does have reflection as well as transmission. In case of $E<V_0$, the transmission wave is exponentially decaying $\sim e^{-kz}$. This means that the probability of finding the transmitted particle is exponentially decreasing. In contrast to $E>V_0$ case, the probability of finding the transmitted particles is finite, even for some special condition, probability is $1$. So saying that the particle is "bounded" in potential barrier is not correct. **Note that the closed system I talked about not the closed system we study in thermodynamics, but a system where we have more than one "barrier".**

Comment: In that case, doesnt it violate the definition of bound state?

Comment: No it doesn't. I don't know what you learn a definition of bound state is but the system doesn't have a bound state. According to Wikipedia  "In quantum physics, a bound state is a quantum state of a particle subject to a potential such that the particle has a tendency to remain localized in one or more regions of space.". In your case, the transmitted particle is definitely not localized.